# Configure Chrome or Firefox to have an "open link in default browser" action

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, browser-tabs

I would like to open some webapps in a secondary browser, so that they are grouped in a separate window outside of my main browser.

In a secondary browser's webapp, I would like to be able to right-click a link and select "Open in the default browser", so that the link opens in my primary browser.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 6):

Create a browser extension that uses [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/nativeMessaging) to execute `open url` on the command line when you right-click a link.

This is all I could think of. I wanted this too so [I built it for Chrome](https://github.com/kumar303/default-opener).

Comment: Hey @kumar303, thank you for chiming in! I've tried your extension and it didn't work for me. Can I contact you via an instant messenger to figure it out?

Comment: Sorry to hear that. The best thing would be to file a bug in the repo.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10 with Chrome, I have found that opening a link in an incognito window will open a link in a new incognito window if none existed, or open a link in a new tab in an incognito window that does exist.